# How do I require that the user installs another Android app (on which my app depends), during installation of my app?

Tags: android, google-play, installation, google-play-services

In desktop applications, for example, many applications ask us to install .Net framework during their installation.

So my question is that during the installation of my Android application on a user's device, how can I notify the user that this application depends on another application, so they need to install it, and then take them to the Playstore where they can install it?

Comment: You can check if the package name of application which your application depends on, exists or not. If the package name is not found in the device, you can show an alert stating need to install your dependancy application.

Comment: @Prasad Is it possible to open directly the page in Google play app which would install the other app (i.e. the user will not have t type the name of the other app in search bar and carry out search for it in Google play)?

Comment: Yes. We can open through intents.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can not ask them during installation process but you can check on your application launch for particular app (with package name) is installed or not and if not then re-direct it to play store.

Comment: Is it possible to open directly the page in Google play app which would install the other app (i.e. the user will not have t type the name of the other app in search bar and carry out search for it in Google play)?

Comment: yes you can pass the link of the app itself it will directly redirect to that app only like "https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.instagram.android"

Answer (score 2):

DUring installation?  You can't-  there's no installers on Android.  You can make the launcher Activity of your app check if the other app is installed and if not attempt to install it, but that's the best you can do.